# not able to move file received from js in to another folder on linux server using php

Tags: php, linux

- I'm trying to move file received from js using POST to another folder on linux sever using php
- with shell_exec and also printing the move command in one text file for my  reference so that i can verify the command is right or not

**this is my code**

```
$command = "mv ".$file_tmp_name." ".$curr_dir."/wiresharktraces/".$file_name;
$log_string = "command = $command \r\n";    
fwrite($file, $log_string); 
shell_exec("mv ".$file_tmp_name." ".$curr_dir."/wiresharktraces/".$file_name);
```

- this code is running fine when file name are short but for bigger file name the code is not running properly it is not able to move the file
- command = mv /tmp/phpZRDvIp /var/www/html/web/auto/exfo/excelautomation/wiresharktraces/5.3.3.1 Tracking Area Update procedure with Serving GW change(SGW_MME).pcap (this is my log file's output)
- for this file the file is not moved in desired folder but when i change the file name to "ab" the file is moved
- and i have also checked few website for maximum allowed length for mp command which is 131072 bytes much more than my command's length which is 153
- thank you for your help in advance

**found reason not solution**

- the reason for this strange behavior is "spaces" and "()" or any another character except "_" in file name but i want solution because i can not restrict user for file name and i want to save it with same name

Comment: Because the spaces are in filename..

Comment: but then how the same file with different name works properly with same code

Comment: I think you sould use the PHP built 'rename' function, no need call external shell. http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: i want to execute this command too shell_exec("chmod 775 ".$curr_dir."/wiresharktraces/".$file_name);  and php rename gives me "600" as a permission so same problem at this command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is very simple replace the other character(space, (, [, etc) in file name with underscore

```
$file_name = preg_replace("/[^0-9,a-z,A-Z,.]/", "_", $file_name);
```

this will replace all other character except number, alphabet and . so now Linux command will execute safely with no error